# Try catch моего теста

Tags: java, android, try-catch, kotlin

Если я правильно понимаю, основной принцип отлова ошибок `try catch` является в том, чтобы при появлении какой-то определенной - ожидаемой ошибки, возвращать результат значения `true`/`false` ну или сам результат значения.

У меня есть некое выражение (тест), которое проверяет текст в конкретных айдишках, и задача состоит в том, чтобы если текст не совпадал (был отличным от мною ожидаемого), я отлавливал ошибку путём `try`/`catch`.

Вопрос собственно состоит в том, как корректно поместить данное выражение в блок `try`/`catch` так, чтобы при не соответствии одного из параметров "отлавливалась" ошибка:

```
 private val isDialogRunning: Boolean
    get() {
        onView(Matchers.allOf(withId(R.id.titleTextView), ViewMatchers.withText("Warning")))
                .check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()))
        return true
    }
```

- как определить саму ошибку? Ну, то есть я примерно знаю, какая ошибка вылетит, если будут некорректные данные, но как её в catch правильно будет прописать?

Comment: а в чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: а в чём вопрос собственно? И да, это конечно холивар, но исключение не предназначено для "ожидаемых ошибок", на то оно и исключение...

Answer (score 2):

Исключения предназначены для ошибок которые происходят редко и которые программа/библиотека не можете предотвратить или исправить. Исключения не следует использовать для организации нормального (без ошибок) потока управления программы.

Исключения полезны, если вы создаете библиотеку и заранее не можете понять, как именно будет обработаны ошибки. Используя исключения вы даете программисту, который использует вашу библиотеку, возможность сделать обработку ошибок.